# Angular: Path when url parameter has ? in it

Tags: angular, url, parameters, path, routes

I have URL like localhost:4200/user/contact and localhost:4200/user/contact/1 where "1" is the parameter returning the id.

For that my routinng.ts is like...

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'user',
      children: [
        {
          path="",
          component: UserComponent,
        },
        {
          path="contact",
          component: UserContactComponent,
        },
        {
          path="contact/:id",
          component: UserComponent,
        },
      ]
    },
];`
```

But when the URL is localhost:4200/user/contact/1?name=abc&value=65767 then it does not works 
"1?name=abc&value=65767" does not returns as a single parameter. What should be my path in this case?

Answer (score 1):

All the key=value that follows the ? character are treated as queryParams and not as "path" params.

To get these values, you have to use the queryParamMap on the ActivatedRouteSnapshot in your user component